# How to use pandas aggregate with custom function

Tags: python, pandas

I am puzzled by the behavior of the pandas function agg(). When I pass a custom aggregator without first calling groupy(), then the aggregation fails. Why does this happen?

Specifically, when I run the following code ...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def mymean(series):
    return np.mean(series)

frame = pd.DataFrame()
frame["a"] = [1,2,3]
display(frame.agg(["mean"]))
display(frame.agg([mymean]))
frame["const"] = 0
display(frame.groupby("const").agg(["mean"]))
display(frame.groupby("const").agg([mymean]))
```

... I obtain this:

[image]

In the second of the four calls to agg(), aggregation fails. Why is that? What I want is to be able to compute custom summary statistics on a frame without first calling groupby() so that I obtain a frame where each row corresponds to one statistic (mean, kurtosis, other stuff...)

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I wonder something very similiar to this a while back and submitted a bug report.  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25454

Comment: If you just pass the function with out the brackets you'll get your expected results.  `frame.agg(mymean)`.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you for your response. The issue is that I would like to use more than one aggregator, i.e. have [mymean, mystd, mysomethingelse]. So I can't remove the list. The code above is just a minimal example.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you for your response. I actually want the opposite. groupby(level=0) would turn each row into its own group. However, I want to compute the statistic over the entire column, i.e. I want the entire column to be its own group.

Comment: Ah.. okay... my bad.